# Azure Stack and Ansible

Tags: ansible, azure-stack

There is no azure stack ansible modules in the latest ansible 2.7. 
There are two things i want to know.
1. Is it feasible to customize azure ansible modules to work for azure stack?
2. If yes for the first question,what are the features which are only available in azure stack which cannot be invoked using azure modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can use old azure ansible module with Azure Stack because Azure Stack doesn't support a new API version. The latest ansible uses a new API version. So you must use old ansible to use the old API version. I confirmed that ansible 2.4 work with ASDK 1901.

Answer (score 0):

The Ansible playbooks simply call Azure Resource Manager API, so in most cases they will work the same as in public Azure. With that said, Azure Stack does not support all of the same APIs and versions that public Azure does so you will have to match your version.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ansible/ansible-matrix

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-considerations?view